# package org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.UaTcpStackClient not found using intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, opc-ua

Im doing a project where Im required to establish an OPC UA connection using Java.
I have done my research and it seems like the easiest way is using eclipse.milo library/package.
A lot of example codes I've seen use the package I mentioned in the title, but my IDE can´t find it.

Im using Maven, this is what I have in my pom.xml regarding this package:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.milo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't think this is the problem since IntelliJ is fine with other packages from eclipse.milo like:

```
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.structured.EndpointDescription;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.OpcUaClient;
import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.api.config.OpcUaClientConfigBuilder;
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's no UaTcpStackClient class under the package.
https://github.com/eclipse/milo/tree/master/opc-ua-stack/stack-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/stack/client